# Retrieving jQuery data from dynamic HTML element returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to retrieve data from a variable HTML element. On click, the id of the `<span>` element is retrieved, which I want to enable me to dynamically `$([dynamic id])` select that element and request the data stored in the data attribute.

My jQuery looks like this:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( ".checkmark" ).on( "click", ( event ) => {
        let checkBoxId = "#" + event.target.id, // #checkBox1
            checkBoxData = event.target.id + "-value", // checkBox1-value
            checkBoxValue = $( checkBoxId ).data( checkBoxData ); // undefined
    } );
} );
```

The HTML element targeted looks like this:

```
<span class="checkmark" id="checkBox1" data-checkBox1-value=-155></span>
```

The value of let checkBoxValue is undefined and I cannot figure out why.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning `undefined` because it is declared incorrectly. The part after `data-` should be in lower case. In your case, it must be

```
<span class="checkmark" id="checkbox1" data-checkbox1-value=-155></span>
```

for the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can get attribute value of span using [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function in `jQuery`

```
checkBoxValue = $(checkBoxId).attr(checkBoxData);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are having scope issues with the new `()=>{}` syntax.

So, you will need to bind `this` to the function event handler using `{self:this}`. If you don't want to do this, you can use the old `function(){}` syntax instead.

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( ".checkmark" ).on( "click", {self:this}, ( event ) => {
        var checkBoxValue = $(this).data("checkbox1-value")
        alert(checkBoxValue);
    } );
} );
```

And also as @Erwin mentioned, use only lowercase in your `data-` attribute name:

```
<span class="checkmark" id="checkbox1" data-checkbox1-value="-155"></span>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vx909jtL/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response guys. Love this developer community. :)

Comment: @Wasbeer That is great to know <3. Please upvote any helpful answers and select a [best answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/320395) as well

Answer (score 1):

The `checkBoxId` variable is unnecessary because you can use the `this` keyword since it is the current element you are working with.

```
$(function() {
    $(".checkmark").on("click", (event) => {
        let checkBoxData = event.target.id + "-value";
        let checkBoxValue = $(this).data(checkBoxData);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me try it ;)

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( ".checkmark" ).on( "click",  function()  {
        var checkBoxId = "#" + $(this).attr('id');
          var  checkBoxData =  $(this).attr('id') + "-value";
        $( this ).attr('data-'+ checkBoxData, 155 );
    } );
});
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/mawad/ro3rog39/)